# Como cargar valores en un modal html5 desde a href

Tags: php, html, modal, codeigniter-3

hola comunidad estoy tratando de cargar datos desde un link href hacia un Modal html5 quiero obtener los valores de el metodo update_data_admin en el modal para asi llamarlos con un foreach desde el Modal de html creo q el problema esta en el href y el parametro ID

este es el view

```
<tbody>
                <?php foreach ($this->Main_model->fetch_data()->result() as $value) {   ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $value->ID; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value->Ubicacion; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value->Nombre; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value->Mac_SN; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value->InventarioID; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value->ReferenciaEquipo; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $value->CostoEquipo; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "<a href = '".base_url()."Admin_contoller/update_data_admin/".$value->ID." class ='dropdown-item' data-toggle ='modal' data-target='#insertModal'>Editar</a></td>";?></td>
                  <td><?php echo "<a href = '".base_url()."main/delete_data/" .$value->ID."'>Borrar</a>";?></td>
                <?php } ?>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
```

Estos son mis 2 metodos del COntroller

```
public function update_data_admin()
  {    
    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data["user_data"] = $this->Main_model->fetch_single_data($user_id);
    $data["fetchData"] = $this->Main_model->fetch_data();
    $this->load->view("admin", $data);

  }
public function Update_htmlData()
  {
    $data = $array = array(
      'Ubicacion' =>$this->input->post('ubicacion'),
      'Nombre' =>$this->input->post('nombre'),
      'Mac_SN' =>$this->input->post('mac'),
      'InventarioID' =>$this->input->post('inventario'),
      'ReferenciaEquipo' =>$this->input->post('referencia'),
      'CostoEquipo' =>$this->input->post('costo')
     );

    if(isset($_POST['update_model']))
    {
      $this->Main_model->update_data($data, $this->input->post("hidden_id"));
      redirect(base_url(). "main/updated");
    }

  }
```

Este el html del modal

```
<!-- Modal Insertar Regisytos-->
<div class="modal fade" id="insertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar Equipos</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal Actualzar Password-->
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method ="post" action="<?php echo base_url()?>Admin_contoller/Update_htmlData">
        <?php
          var_dump($data['user_data']);
         ?>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Ubicacion</label>
          <input type="text" name="ubicacion" class="form-control" id="ubicacion" placeholder="" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">InventarioID</label>
          <input type="text" name="inventario" class="form-control" id="inventario" placeholder="InventarioID" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">ReferenciaEquipo</label>
          <input type="text" name="referencia" class="form-control" id="referencia" placeholder="ReferenciaEquipo" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">CostoEquipo</label>
          <input type="text" name="costo" class="form-control" id="costo" placeholder="CostoEquipo" required/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" name="update_model" values="update" class="btn btn-info">Save changes</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php // echo $row->ID;  ?>">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<a href = '".base_url()."Admin_contoller/update_data_admin/".$value->ID.` cuando realizas esto no te cargara el modal, debes valerte de `AJAX` por ejemplo, para solicitar información en el controller y cargar los datos que obtienes en el modal para **Editar**

Comment: Cesar romero , no estoy muy bien en Ajax podrias ponerme un ejemplo , encontre uno pero no me funciona

Comment: <script >
     $(document).on("click",".insertModal", function(){
        valor_IDcontrato = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "clientes/Clientes_controller/contrato_view",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"html",
            data:{id:valor_IDcontrato},
            done:function(data){
                $("#insertModal .modal-body").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>